# Get session key from the Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I use the Graph API: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=aap_id&redirect_uri=url&response_type=token` and I get an access token.

*How I can get the session key from it or from the Graph?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, but there's also no reason you'd need a session key; all the old APIs which used to require a session key were retired or updated to take the access token.

Comment: Indeed, the session key is needed when you want to log out the authenticated user from your web application for example. Using the API graph :  https://facebook.com/logout.php?app_key=APP_KEY&session_key=SESSION_KEY&next=YOUR_LOGOUT_URL

Comment: That's not a graph API endpoint - which documentation are you working from which mentions that URL?

Comment: I already post a question about this point : here the link : [My question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730094/how-to-get-facebook-session-key-in-java). Thanks

Comment: The link wasn't correctly posted in my previous comment